# Cron tar with file filtering

Tags: linux, cron, tar

I need to change the following cron so that it only tars images with a pattern of: l_*.jpg
What modifications does my current cron require?

```
0 4 * * 1 tar vcf /home/XXXXXX/public_html/backups/monday_backup.tar /home/XXXXXX/public_html/images/products
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
0 4 * * 1   find /home/XXXXXX/public_html/images/products -iname "l_*.jpg" | tar vcf /home/XXXXXX/public_html/backups/monday_backup.tar --files-from=-
```

It's really simple to create a script-file. 
Just make a text file with content.

```
#!/bin/bash
date
echo It is a blue day
```

Place that file into private folder (folder not accessable by browser) on the host.
Using cpanel set executable permissions on it.

Try to run it from cron:

```
*/2 * * * *   /home/XXXXXX/private_scripts/backup-script 2>&1 >> /home/XXXXXX/private_scripts/backup-log
```

Check content of /home/XXXXXX/private_scripts/backup-log. If you see messages 'It is a blue day', than cron setup and script are ok.

If you don't see anything, then try to replace '`#!/bin/bash`' with '`#!/bin/sh`'. Double check paths.

If you setup script successesfully, then add to the end of script the line:

```
find /home/XXXXXX/public_html/images/products -iname "l_*.jpg" | tar vcf /home/XXXXXX/public_html/backups/monday_backup.tar --files-from=-
```

Comment: Didnt work but I'm afraid I dont have enough experience to find the reason.

Comment: Do you know how to create a simple shell script file and run it on the host?

Comment: BTW, most hosting providers do daily backups of site which can be accessed using site control panel. So may be it is easier for you to use standard solution.

Comment: I know that, I need to perform additional backups though. @alexander: I know how to set a cron in CPanel but not on a console.